# Pydantic - Validation Does not Happen

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am quite new to using Pydantic.

The Issue I am facing right now is that the Model Below is not raising the Expected Exception when the value is out of range.

For example, if you pass -1 into this model it should ideally raise an HTTPException. but nothing happens

I am not sure where I might be going wrong.

Any Advice would be great.

```
class GetInput:
    """
    for the fields endpoint
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 rank: Optional[int] = None,
                 interval: Optional[int] = None):

        self.rank = rank
        self.interval = interval

    @validator('rank')
    def check_if_rank_in_range(cls, v):
        """
        check if input rank is within range
        """
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:

            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=400, detail="Rank Value Must be within range (0,1000000)")
        return v

    @validator('interval')
    def check_if_interval_in_range(cls, v):
        """
        check if input rank is within range
        """
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:

            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=400, detail="Interval Value Must be within range (0,1000000)")
        return v
```

The FastAPI Endpoint

```
@router.get('fields/',status_code=200)
def get_data(params: GetInput = Depends()):
    
    if params.rank:
        result = get_info_by_rank(params.rank)

    elif params.interval:

        result = get_info_by_interval(params.interval)
    
    return result
```

Comment: you aren't inheriting from `BaseModel`...

Comment: When I inherit the BaseModel This is the Error I run into ```pydantic.errors.ConfigError: Validators defined with incorrect fields: check_if_interval_in_range, check_if_rank_in_range (use check_fields=False if you're inheriting from the model and intended this)```

Comment: Because you didn't annotate your fields.

Comment: The Validations did not happen even after I annotated the fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class GetInput(BaseModel):

    rank: Optional[int]=None
    interval: Optional[int]=None
    
    @validator("*")
    def check_range(cls, v):
        if v: 
            if not 0 < v < 1000001:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Value Must be within range (0,1000000)")
            return v
```

- the validator was not working due to not Inheriting the BaseModel Class
- When the BaseModel Class would get inherited it would throw an error if either of the values is empty thus the additional if statement.